# vim: Insert output of command at cursor instead of next line

Tags: vim, uuid

I have a shortcut in my .vimrc file that generates a uuid and inserts it into my buffer:

```
com! Uuid r ! uuidgen | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"
```

When I invoke it, it inserts the uuid on the next line. However, I want vim to insert the uuid where my cursor is, not on the next line. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the command:

```
:com! Uuid exe "normal! i".system('uuidgen | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" | tr -d "\n"')
```